# How can i route to an external link without appending to current link?

Tags: reactjs, routes, hyperlink, tags

when I press the image I have running on my port, the `current.link` link is appended to my current link as such `localhost:3000/current.link` - assuming that current.link has a value. how can I route to an external link with out that issue?

below you is my code :

```
const ContCard = ({content,col}) => {
  return (
                

                <div  className={`col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-${col} my-3`}>
                    <div className='card p-3 rounded'  >
                            <a
                                to={content.link}
                                target="_blank" 
                                rel="noreferrer"                    
                            >
                                <img 
                                    className='card-image-top mx-auto'
                                    src= {content.images[0].url} 
                                    width="250" height="200"
                                    
                                />
                          </a>                  
                        <div className='card-body d-flex flex-column'>
                            <h5 className='card-title'>
                                <div> {content.title}</div>
                            </h5>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
  )
}

export default ContCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely based on what value `content.link` *has*.  The example you give:

```
localhost:3000/current.link
```

Implies that the value is *literally* `"current.link"`.  That's not a URL to any external location, so the browser has no reason to interpret it like that.

Taking a step back and thinking about how a browser interprets URLs, where in this list does a URL *definitely* become "external"?:

- `index.html`
- `index.domain`
- `runScript.com`
- `www.html`
- `www.com`
- `google.html`
- `google.com`

The answer is *nowhere*.  From the browser's perspective, there is no *structural* difference to any of those.  They're all referencing a resource relative to the current resource.

If you want the browser to treat the URL as a fully-qualified URL, it needs to be complete.  For example, this is relative to the current resource:

- `google.com`

But *this* is an entirely new resource:

- `//google.com`

That is, while you don't necessarily need the `http:` or `https:` part of the protocol/scheme, you *do* need the `//` part to specify that this is the root of a fully-qualified resource.